# How to make CSS3 animations to work in IE 8/9?

Tags: html, css

I have been practicing CSS3 animations, but they don't work in IE 9/8.

**Is there a way to make CSS3 animations to work in IE 8/9?**

Comment: Could you show some examples of css3 animations that your trying to make it work? because the question is quite general. If you show some animations that you want it to make it work, I could help you get some alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Here's [CSS3 browser support](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp) Reference

Comment: I suppose what `sef4eg` is saying is that, you can only expect CSS3 features which are supported in IE 8/9 - to work in IE 8/9.

Answer (score 0):

A [polyfiller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill) might provide the functionality that you seek in IE 8/9.

> In web development, a polyfill (or polyfiller) is additional code
>   which provides facilities that are not built into a web browser.

*(Wikipedia)*

The [Polyfiller page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill#Examples) in Wikipedia lists several Polyfillers.

One of which, [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/), uses JavaScript to make many CSS3 selectors work in IE 8 and below.

[image]